# React and MaterialUI - GridLayout using papers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, material-ui

I'm using react-grid-layout library to create an adapting grid which each item is a paper component from react material ui.

I'm having a problem when running the application I receive in the broswer:
"TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createContext is not a function"
Under the module of "./node_modules/@material-ui/styles/esm/useTheme/ThemeContext.js"

I'm pretty new to react and all so maybe I've done something very stupid but help will be much appreciated because I'm kind of clueless :)

The Home component is:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import { Paper } from 'material-ui';
import React from 'react';
import GridLayout from 'react-grid-layout';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        padding: theme.spacing(3,2),
    },
}));

class Home extends React.Component {


    render() {
        var layout = [
            {i: 'a', x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2, static: true},
            {i: 'b', x: 1, y: 0, w: 3, h: 2, minW: 2, maxW: 4},
            {i: 'c', x: 4, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2}
        ];

        const { classes } = this.props;

        return (
            <GridLayout className="layout" layout={layout} cols={12} rowHeight={30} width={1200}>
                <Paper className={classes.root}>
                    <Typography key="a" variant="h5" component="h3">
                        This is a set of paper!
                    </Typography>
                </Paper>
                <Paper className={classes.root}>
                    <Typography key="b" variant="h5" component="h3">
                        This is a set of paper!
                    </Typography>
                </Paper>
                <Paper className={classes.root}>
                    <Typography key="c" variant="h5" component="h3">
                        This is a set of paper! 
                    </Typography>
                </Paper>
            </GridLayout>
        );
    }


    /* 
    <MapContainer latitude={31.97973975} longitude={34.74769792490634}/>
    */
}

export default withStyles(useStyles)(Home);
```

This is the App.js file:

```
import { MuiThemeProvider } from 'material-ui/styles';
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Home from './pages/Home';

class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider>
                <Router>
                    <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
                </Router>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Package.json dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.7.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "google-maps-react": "^2.0.2",
    "mobx": "^5.15.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
    "react-grid-layout": "^0.17.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
```

Thank you heads up!

Comment: looks like you need to update react. Which version you use ?

Comment: I've modified the question with my dependencies.
Why the version causes this error?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the following in the Material-UI documentation (https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/#npm):

> Please note that react >= 16.8.0 and react-dom >= 16.8.0 are peer dependencies.

Material-UI v4 is dependent on React hooks and context -- neither of which are in React 15 (shown in your dependencies).